# Hibernate ManyToOne syntax

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to make a code to using MSSQL + Hibernate/JPA where I could entry some products and make a FK on it referring to a company.

my relation is that way

```java
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyId")
    private Set<Product> product;
```

```java
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "companyId")
    private Company companyId;
```

But rather then take the FK that I send in my JSON it creates a new company

This is the JSON:

```
{
    "name":"Test",
    "price":"35.63",
    "productCompanyId":"10293", (this is the ID on company receipt, to make )
    "companyId":"2"
}
```

here my entities

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @NotNull
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyId")
    private Set<Product> product;

    public Company(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    int productCompanyId; //product code in company receipt, making easier later updates

    @NotNull
    String name;

    @NotNull
    java.math.BigDecimal price;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "companyId")
    private Company companyId;// identification of where it was purchased

    public Product(String name, java.math.BigDecimal price, int productCompanyId, Company companyId) {

        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
        this.productCompanyId = productCompanyId;
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

}
```

Database:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtRWR.jpg

```
id  name
1   TestCompany1
2   TestCompany2
3   2
```

```
id  name    price   product_company_id  company_id
1   Test    35.63   10293   3
```

I Think the problem is here:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Product> insertProduct (@RequestBody ProductForm form){
        Product product = form.creationConverter();
        productRepository.save(product);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
public class ProductForm {

    @NotNull
    String name;

    @NotNull
    java.math.BigDecimal price;

    @NotNull
    int productCompanyId;

    @NotNull
    Company companyId;

    public Product creationConverter() {
        return new Product(name, price, productCompanyId, companyId);
    }

    public Product updateConverter(Integer id, ProductRepository productRepository) {
        Product product = productRepository.getOne(id);
        product.setName(this.name);
        product.setPrice(this.price);
        product.setProductCompanyId(this.productCompanyId);
        product.setCompanyId(companyId);
        return product;
    }
}
```

But I can't find a way to set this companyId to int (I'm sending a new objetc to controller, it's expected the creation  of new company instead of just linking it)

Comment: How you are persisting the Product  entity, see if you can set company during product save.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understood exactly what you ask.
I'm using lombok annotations (@Data) and JPA. I have another class "form" with constructors to save using productRepository.

Comment: How the entity(Product) get created before submitting it to save or persist. You should be passing entity in .save() or .persist() method.

Comment: @PrashantKatara I just updated the code with something that I learned yesterday.
I started coding not much time ago and isn't familiar to me all the terms used to reffer to Classes, etc...

Comment: Ok no problem, refer some YouTube video to get it clear, ultimately when an entity is in  transient state then you need to set the company ID to Product along with product data and after that  do perform persit() or save() operation to move in  persistence state, then you can commit and flush it to databse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some tests and reading a lot of stuff I find the problem isn't my relation. But my ProductForm.java

What I did to fix it is a quite simple in fact.
First I remove my @ManyToOne relation, because it force me to create a Company variable in my Product
Leaving only @OneToMany in company.
It this way I could use a int variable "companyId" in my product and the records in database stops to duplicate =)

This is how worked:

Product:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    int productCompanyId; //product code in company receipt, making easier later updates

    @NotNull
    String name;

    @NotNull
    java.math.BigDecimal price;

    @NotNull
    int companyId;// identification of where it was purchased

    public Product(String name, java.math.BigDecimal price, int productCompanyId, int companyId) {

        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
        this.productCompanyId = productCompanyId;
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

}
```

ProductForm:

```java
@Data
public class ProductForm {

    @NotNull
    String name;

    @NotNull
    java.math.BigDecimal price;

    @NotNull
    int productCompanyId;

    @NotNull
    int companyId;

    public Product creationConverter() {
        return new Product(name, price, productCompanyId, companyId);
    }

    public Product updateConverter(Integer id, ProductRepository productRepository) {
        Product product = productRepository.getOne(id);
        product.setName(this.name);
        product.setPrice(this.price);
        product.setProductCompanyId(this.productCompanyId);
        product.setCompanyId(companyId);
        return product;
    }
}
```

And then the company with the relation:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Company {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @NotNull
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyId")
    private Set<Product> product;

    public Company(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```